# Indirect way to reference "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\datasvcutil.exe" in a prebuild event

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, prebuild, pre-build-event

I am running the datasvcutil.exe command in a prebuild event.

datasvcutil.exe is located in "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319" (on 64 bit machines.)

I can just hard code this as C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\datasvcutil.exe, but that seems rather brittle. When a hypothetical .net v4.0.30320 comes out my prebuild event will not work anymore.

With the Visual Studio Command prompt, I can call datasvcutil.exe with out the path.  I am wondering if there is a similar indirect way to call this from my pre-build event command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the tool you need is in the same path as `MSBuild.exe` you could simply reference it with `$(MSBuildBinPath)\DataSvcUtil.exe` which would make it also independent of *Framework / Framework64*

Comment: Perfect!  Just what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

I like Filburts answer above. But if you really want to be courageous, you can invoke:

```
%VS100COMNTOOLS%\VCVarsQueryRegistry.bat
rem and query one of the %FrameworkDIR32% or %FrameworkDIR64% environment variables, depending on your choice
```

If you are even more courageous, MSBuild is capable of reading registry by itself - the following link may help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171458.aspx (check the "Registry Properties" section)